# Copy multiple sheets with similar sheet names into a new workbook

Tags: vba

I would like to copy specific sheets (which have similar sheet names) to a new workbook.

I saw that other users have previously used an array to list out the names of the specific sheets that they would like to be copied. However, this is not feasible for me as I have over 100 sheets to copy over. E.g. Fund 1, Fund 2, ... Fund 100.

As such, is there some wildcard that I could use? Like sheet name contains "Fund*"?

Comment: You could use the [`Like`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/like-operator) operator. Or [`InStr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/instr-function).

Comment: You can also use `InStr(1, ws.Name, "Fund", vbTextCompare)` .. to check if name contains `Fund`. Where `ws.name` is your worksheet name.

Answer (score 0):

Something Like this should do the job for you:

```
For Each ws In Worksheets

    If InStr(1, ws.Name, "fund", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

        'Statement to move the sheet

    End If

Next
```

`Instr` will return 0 if `Fund` is not found and `>0` if found in the name of the worksheet.